# How to update new column in data-frame with specific column from another data-frame with duplicated in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Hello all My df1 looks like

```
MNO  DOB
123  NA
123  NA
234  NA
234  NA
345  NA
456  NA
456  NA
```

My df2  have

```
MNO  DOB
123  22-04-1996
234  16-06-1994
345  05-05-1990
456  18-08-2000
```

I used merge to get results using df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by.x = "MNO",all.x = TRUE)

I get output looks like

```
MNO  DOB
123  22-04-1996
123  NA
234  16-06-1994
234  NA
345  05-05-1990
456  18-08-2000
456  NA
```

Expected results :

```
MNO  DOB
123  22-04-1996
123  22-04-1996
234  16-06-1994
234  16-06-1994
345  05-05-1990
456  18-08-2000
456  18-08-2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed, the columns should be merged by the same column 'MNO', so we can use `by` instead of `by.x`

```
merge(df1[1], df2, by = "MNO", all.x = TRUE)
#  MNO        DOB
#1 123 22-04-1996
#2 123 22-04-1996
#3 234 16-06-1994
#4 234 16-06-1994
#5 345 05-05-1990
#6 456 18-08-2000
#7 456 18-08-2000
```

---

If the output of 'df3' is based on a different code, after the `merge` step we can `fill` from `tidyr` to fill the NA elements with the previous non-NA

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df3 %>%
             fill(DOB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `data.table` with `roll=T` option:

```
merge(dx[,list(MNO)],dx2,roll=TRUE)

 MNO        DOB
1: 123 22-04-1996
2: 123 22-04-1996
3: 234 16-06-1994
4: 234 16-06-1994
5: 345 05-05-1990
6: 456 18-08-2000
7: 456 18-08-2000
```